# Spring WebFlux throws 'producer' type is unknow when I return value in the response body

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm using Spring Boot with Kotlin, and now trying to get status value from a GET restful service by passing a handler for a reactive service.

I can see that the handler I'm passing is in the request, but whenever I'm building the body, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'producer' type is unknown to ReactiveAdapterRegistry
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException
```

**Here is my code**:

```
@Bean
    fun getReceiptConversionStatus() = router {
        accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
            GET("/BsGetStatus/{handler}", ::handleGetStatusRequest)
        }
    }
    private fun handleGetStatusRequest(serverRequest: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> = ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(GetStatusViewmodel(fromObject(serverRequest.pathVariable("handler"))), GetStatusViewmodel::class.java)
            .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build())
```

and that's my Viewmodel:

```
data class GetStatusViewmodel(
        @JsonProperty("handler") val documentHandler: String
)
```

Answer (score 40):

For me, I was doing something like this:

```
webClient.post()
    .uri("/some/endpoint")
    .body(postRequestObj, PostRequest.class) // erroneous line 
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(PostResponse.class)
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
```

When looking at the springs docs for that function `body()`, this is what's explained:

```
Variant of body(Publisher, Class) that allows using any producer that can be resolved to Publisher via ReactiveAdapterRegistry.

Parameters:
     producer - the producer to write to the request
     elementClass - the type of elements produced

Returns:
    this builder
```

So the first parameter can't just be *any* object, it *has* to be a producer. Changing my above code to wrap my object around in a Mono fixed this issue for me.

```
webClient.post()
    .uri("/some/endpoint")
    .body(Mono.just(postRequestObj), PostRequest.class)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(PostResponse.class)
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
```

reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestBodySpec.html

Comment: Based on your example,
You can also use `bodyValue` instead of `body` it helps you avoid wrapping the object into a **Mono**. The concerning line will look like
`bodyValue(postRequestObj)`

Comment: @ValdèseKamdem the 'bodyValue' function worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

`Flux` and `Mono`s are `Producers`. They produce stuff. You are not passing in a `producer` in the body thats why you get the error, it doesn't recognize the producer you are passing, because you are passing in a `GetStatusViewmodel`.

Your body needs to be of type `Mono<GetStatusViewmodel>`. You can either replace `body` with `bodyValue` (it will automatically wrap it for you) or you can wrap your `GetStatusViewodel` in a `Mono` using `Mono#just` before passing it into the `body` function.

Comment: `syncBody` is now deprecated

Comment: Only in Spring ecosystem would this kind of thing be a runtime error and not a compile time error!

Answer (score 4):

I actually solved it, and I will post it here just in case somebody would do the same mistake I did :( It was a typical mistake for those who work with Java, **it was a wrong import**.

I was using `fromObject()` method in my application *"I updated the question to match my actual code"*. You can find this function in both of these imports, and I was using one of the overloaded `body()` functions to pass this wrong placed function:

```
//this is the wrong import I was using
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.EntityResponse.fromObject
//this is the correct one for building the mono body
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.fromObject
```

By using the method from `BodyInserters`, you will be able to pass `fromObject(T)` to the body method and it will return the mono result.

Answer (score 2):

The specified code resolved the issue

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getName(ServerRequest request) {

    return ServerResponse.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(birthday);

}
```

Comment: It also solved mine. I was using .body and changing it to .bodyValue sovled it.